# Can someone intuitively explain how tree traversal works?

Tags: c++, tree

I'm trying to restore memory allocated in a tree by traversing the tree and deleting the memory as necessary.  For example, suppose I have the following tree structure:

```
struct tree
{
   int *value;
   tree *left;
   tree *right;
}

tree *root; //always points to the root of this tree
```

I know that we have to visit each `value` after every recursive call, delete it, then move to the next node (which can be `left` or `right`), but the recursive process seems very counter intuitive (particularly the part where we move to the left or move to the right).

I'm trying to follow the rule of "do something with the root, recursively call the left, then recursively call the right," but the way the code functions is confusing to me.  How can I preserve the invariant of `root`?  If someone can perhaps explain the concept pictorially that would be great.

Comment: [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tree_traversal) has a graphic and some descriptive text that may help.

Comment: It helps to think about each node in isolation -- for any one node, what do you want to do? If you want to do the same thing to each node, the recursion follows naturally. The only special thing about the root is it's the first node you look at.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as you need the tree for traversal during delete the idea is to delete on return

```
void del_tree(tree *t) {

  if (t->left) {
    // there is a left subtree existing. delete it
    del_tree(t->left);  // first go deeper on left side
    // left branch now completely empty
    delete t->left;     // nothing left behind t->left
    t->left=0;          // just in case
  } else {
    // there is no left subtree existing
    // we are in a leaf or in an unbalanced node
  }

  if (t->right) {
    // there is a right subtree existing. delete it
    del_tree(t->right);  // now go deeper on right side
    // right branch now completely empty
    delete t->right;     // nothing left behind t->right
    t->right=0;          // just in case
  } else {
    // there is no rigt subtree existing
    // we are in a leaf or this was an unbalanced node
    // (before we deleted the left subtree)
  }

  // both branches are now completely empty
  // either they were from the beginning (leaf)
  // or we have successfully reduced this node to a leaf
  // now do the node visit

  if (t->value) {
    delete t->value;     // tidy up
    t->value=0;          // just in case
  }
  // now we are completely clean and empty
  // after return t will be deleted
}

void main() {
  tree *my_tree;

  // stuff

  del_tree(my_tree);   // delete the whole tree
  delete my_tree;      // delete the remaining root node
}
```

a very important aspect on recursion is when to stop. i assume that a NULL pointer in your struct indicates that there is no subtree.

the strategy is now to go as deep as possible `if (t->left) del_tree(t->left);` 
when we reach a NULL pointer on both, left and right we are stranded in a leaf. we now clean the leaf (deleting value) and return. on return `delete t->left;` is executed, this node has nothing left on the left subtree and continues on its right subtree.

here i found a nice image of the [traversal](http://www.flickr.com/photos/bjoernknafla/5622204938/)

---

the problem of deleting a tree is divided into 3 parts. deleting the left subtree, deleting the right subtree and cleaning up self. the deleting of a subtree (left or right) is very much the same procedure as deleting the tree itself. so you use the same function, this is called recursion.

think of deleting a file system structure. you decide for the strategy to delete the 'left' folder structure first, then you delete the subtree 'right' and finally you delete the file 'value'. when during the execution of this strategy you change into a folder (no matter whether left or right) you notice that the problem looks the same. so you apply this strategy again to any folder in the tree.

what happens is, that you change into the directory left repeatedly unless there is no more directory in the current one. you delete the file 'value'. then you go back one folder and delete the folder named 'left'. now you look for a folder named 'right', change into it, find no folders, delete file 'value' and return to the previous folder. you delete the now empty 'right' and finally delete the file 'values as well. next is to do a further return (backtracking). and so on.

you cannot delete non empty folders during going deeper. you have to delete when retreating.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how the if(t->left) and if(t->right) blocks work?

Comment: In C/C++, anything that evaluates to 0 is "false" and anything that isn't 0 is "true". Therefore `if(t->left)` checks if they're null (0). It's syntactically equivalent to `if(t->left != 0)`

Comment: I'm still confused.  If you do if(t->left)...del_tree(t->left) then it goes all the way down the left side of the tree and finally deletes the last node?  What about all the other nodes before the last one?  Why is the "left branch completely gone" after the first if block?

Answer (score 0):

You can think about your tree as a tree with a root and two leafs and each of the leafs point to the root of an other tree.

In fact, this is how you preserve the "invariant of the root", because as soon as you follow a pointer of a leaf, you end up at the root of an other tree.

```
root -> branch -> leaf
|
V
branch -> leaf
```

can be also considered as

```
root -> tree1
|
V
tree2
```

which is in turn

```
root -> (root -> leaf)
|
V
(root -> leaf)
```

So when you follow a branch in the original, you end up in a root again.